# Monitoring Tomcat processes CPU spikes

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, monitoring, tomcat8

We have several Tomcat servers (in AWS) running under Debian, we have all of them instrumented with Cloudwatch metrics for overall performance (Memory, CPU and others). We've detected that in a few of them we have "spikes" of either CPU or Memory utilization, and we'd like do detect what is actually clogging those resources. As all the server runs is java based inside a Tomcat container, the logical would be to hook up some kind of JVM profiler and visually monitor the threads in it, but as we do have Cloudwatch alerts enabled when exceeding a certain threshold (for example CPU over 90%), we'd like to trigger some kind of automated stats collection to see what actual Java thread/code is the root cause of such consumption.

Is there any monitoring agent and/or performance collection tool that might help to diagnose those specific spikes and not needing to collect stats for an actually long running process?

We've already tried trial versions of New Relic, DataDog, and Dynatrace (the latest being the most useful, prohibitively expensive due to its business model not suitable for small companies.), but these solutions gather EVERYTHING, not only required timing windows, as I've asked above...these could work but introduces quite an overhead to the servers if being used 100% time in production servers (where the problem arises and, not in pre-production ones.).

Comment: Possible improvements to this question are being discussed on Meta : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358401/making-my-questions-better/358407

Comment: The main stackoverflow section is for code related queries. You don't have any code in your question. You should repost it in another section and delete it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to setup a pre-production environment and run load tests (with tools like [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/index.html)) in conjunction with server-side monitoring.

Tomcat backends can be monitored using the JMX protocol.

You have 2 solutions :

- **Free**: JMeter with [Perfmon Agent](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonAgent/) to monitor CPU, Memory and custom defined JMX Beans,
- **Freemium** (aka Paid for > 50 concurrent users) : OctoPerf supports [Apache Tomcat monitoring](https://doc.octoperf.com/monitoring/apache-tomcat/), and can monitor your aws servers with an on-premise monitoring agent.

Like always, free software costs nothing but your time, and paid software gets you straight to the issue in exchanges for some pennies.

Comment: I do like JMeter/Perfmon, but I guess I'll be installing it in the production environment (as the server can handle it), and in pre-production, unfortunately, the problem doesn't arise. Regarding JMX Beans, I guess I'll have to study that

Comment: You should also consider solutions like Datadog and/or New Relic for production monitoring.

Comment: I'm currently using AWS' CloudWatch right now for that purposes. New relic clogged my servers (and their support team could fix it) and, I don't remember what happened with Datadog

Comment: I meant "their support team COULDN'T FIX IT" :(